# Getting error while accessing textfield in Android application

Tags: android

I am getting value of EditText e1 in below example as null. So it throws null pointer exception. I wrote below in MainActivity and calling the function calculateSquare upon click on a button. Am i missing something?

```
public void calculateSquare(View view) {
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int square=number * number;
    TextView e2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    e2.setText(square);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="CalculateSquare" 
    android:onClick="calculateSquare"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:text="Square"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your activity_main layout XML....On second thought, when are you calling `calculateSquare`?  `setContentView` should be called in `onCreate`

Comment: Edited with activity_main.xml. Yes the setContentView is there in onCreate function as well.

Comment: You don't need to call `setContentView` again in `calculateSquare` if you called it in `onCreate` (and that's where it belongs).  Can you post your `onCreate()`?

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

Comment: Cleaning the project helped! Thanks user1597833! The null pointer exception did not come when i cleaned and built the project again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in a String as a parameter to the setText().
Change your code to:

```
e2.setText(square+"");
```

When you call `setText(int)` the system will look for the String resource by the given id(int), which needs to be supplied from the R class.

```
e2.setText(R.string.mystring);
```

About the null pointer, try cleaning your project, and you should move the initiation to the onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView( R.layout.activity_main);
  EditText e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  TextView e2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}

public void calculateSquare(View view) {
  int number;
  if (e1.getText().toString().length()>0){
     number = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
     int square=number * number;
     e2.setText(square+"");
  }
}
```

You always need to check if you have entered something in the edittext, since an empty string cannot be converted into an int.

Comment: The exception is thrown on int number = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString()); that is before it reaches the setText()

Comment: The only thing that can be null is e1.  As requested, please post onCreate.  I suspect that you should be declaring e1 at your class (activity) level.

Comment: if it is , so the text you have wrote on the EditText can't be converted to an Integer

Comment: Cleaning the project helped! Thanks user1597833! The null pointer exception did not come when i cleaned and built the project again.